# Syntax Error: Token ':' not a primary expression in modal

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, multi-select

I'm trying to open a modal and I'm getting this error

```
angular.js:10147 Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token ':' not a primary expression at column 1 of the expression [::texts.selectGroup] starting at [::texts.selectGroup].
```

I'm opening the modal with a button click like this

```
<button ng-click="openEmailModal()" class="btn btn-primary">Test Modal</button>
```

Here is my js

```
$scope.emailUsers = [];
      $scope.example1data = [ {label: "David"}, {label:"Jhon"}, {label:"Danny"}];
      $scope.openEmailModal = function() {
          $modal.open({
              templateUrl: 'app/main/notifications/views/details/modal.html',
              windowClass: 'modal-danger',
              resolve: {
                  emailUsers: function() {
                      return $scope.emailUsers;
                  },
                  exampe1data: function() {
                      return $scope.exampe1data;
                  }
              }
          });
      }
```

And here is the html in modal.html that is causing the error

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <div ng-dropdown-multiselect="" options="example1data"
        selected-model="emailUsers"></div>
</div>
```

I think the problem is that the modal doesn't have access to those variables in `options` and `selected-model` so I added the resolve member in modal.open but that didn't fix the error.  How can I resolve this error?

**Update**
I changed the js to this so that I know I'm initializing the variables before I return them and I still get the error. I also changed the data for the dropdown to be an array of strings.  When I debug in chrome it says `emailUsers` is an empty array and `exampe1data` is an array of strings

```
      $scope.openEmailModal = function() {
          $modal.open({
              templateUrl: 'app/main/notifications/views/details/modal.html',
              windowClass: 'modal-danger',
              resolve: {
                  emailUsers: function() {
                      var emailUsers = [];
                      return emailUsers;
                  },
                  exampe1data: function() {
                      var exampe1data = ["David", "Jhon", "Danny"];
                      return exampe1data;
                  }
              }
          });
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that some of your variables return something starting from `:`, and you may check what exactly return these functions:

```
resolve: {
              emailUsers: function() {
                  return $scope.emailUsers;
              },
              exampe1data: function() {
                  return $scope.exampe1data;
              }
          }
```

I predict that you need to convert some of these returns to string. But let's see the log.

**UPDATE**

So, I have found an issue of the module which you are trying to use. [Here is the link](https://github.com/dotansimha/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/issues/22).

The short answer how to fix it:

1. Include [Lodash](https://lodash.com/) lib to your scripts.
2. If that will not solve the issue, switch to [this fork](https://github.com/karthilxg/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect), guy fixed this issue, but pull request had not merged yet.

Comment: @gary69, did you figure out which exactly model gives you this error?

Comment: I can't make the error go away no matter what, it works with a regular dropdown, I'm wondering if its something wrong with how I've included the module or I'm missing css or something. I'm following the example here http://dotansimha.github.io/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/#/

Comment: Could you create a plunker, or do you have a repository to check? because it is difficult to figure out how to fix, without playing around.

Comment: I created one here that's not totally working http://plnkr.co/edit/n9IgaN3rpQfAQMvYNXLc

Comment: Updated my answer, hope it will help you!

Comment: @Mikki Thank you. This answer helped me in tracking the issue. I changed the angular-dropdown-multiselect from 1.11.1 to 1.5.2 in bower json file (Note : Not ^1.5.2). Currently (time of my comment) http://dotansimha.github.io/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/#/ is also having the same issue (Checked in Chrome).

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using isteven multi select because of the issues @Mikki described and I had to add a controller for my modal to inject the data in addition to the `resolve`

```
var EmailModalCtrl = function($modalInstance, usersToEmail) {
      };
      $scope.openEmailModal = function() {
          $scope.usersToEmail = $scope.getUsers();
          $modal.open({
              templateUrl: 'app/main/notifications/views/details/modal.html',
              windowClass: 'modal-danger',
              controller: EmailModalCtrl,
              scope: $scope,
              resolve: {
                  emailUsers: function() {
                      var emailUsers = [];
                      return emailUsers;
                  },
                  exampe1data: function() {
                      return $scope.usersToEmail;
                  }
              }
          });
      }
```